# Which version of jQuery was used in each version of WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Is there anywhere a table with the name "Which version of jQuery was used in each version of WordPress"? Something like:

WP 3.6 — jQuery 1.10.2
WP 3.5 — jQuery 1.8

And so on...

Comment: I dont think such an table exists.

Comment: This can be a good start: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commits/master/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js

Comment: This isn't really a coding question and might be better at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WP Version  /  jQuery Version:

3.6 (in development)    1.9.x
3.5 /   1.8.2
3.4 /   1.7.2
3.3 /   1.7.1
3.2 /   1.6.1
3.1 /   1.4.4
3.0 /   1.4.2
2.9 /   1.3.2

[Source](http://support.sevenspark.com/diagnosis/jquery-version-incorrect/)

You might also find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324692/force-specific-version-jquery-wordpress) helpful if you wish to force WP to use a specific version of jQ