# Wordpress resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with mime type text/html

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I made a little change in functions.php and now some stylesheets don't load and also I'm getting this error in the console everytime I access to my web page:

resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with mime type text/html wordpress

The change I did is update the version of jquery to the latest

Comment: Can you show the code for the changes you made?

Comment: I used this code  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324692/force-specific-version-jquery-wordpress?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this:

By mistake I added 3 white lines in the end of the file functions.php after the "?>".

I deleted those lines and now it works ok.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem too,
by clearing every thing in history of browser; it solved! 
this problem is about browser. if you want be sure, first test it in another browser.